# Why is variance big enough of random by probability result?

Tags: php, linux

Why is variance big enough of random by probability result?

**Test code:**

```
function probability($chances) {

    asort($chances);
    $sum    = array_sum($chances);
    $random = mt_rand(1, $sum);

    foreach($chances as $key => $chance) {
        if($random < $chance)
            return $key;
    }

    return $key;

}

$chances['case1'] = 10;
$chances['case2'] = 30;
$chances['case3'] = 60;

$result = array();

for($i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++)
    @$result[probability($chances)]++;

asort($result);
$sum = array_sum($result);

echo "Case\tCount\tOrig\tResult\n";

foreach($result as $key => $value)
    echo "$key\t$value\t".$chances[$key]."%\t".round($value / $sum * 100)."%\n";
```

**Result:**

```
Case    Count   Orig    Result
case1   14913   10%     15%
case2   33099   30%     33%
Case3   51988   60%     52%
```

Is it possible to adjust it somehow? I was trying to use `mt_srand()`, but it doesn't help.

**Info:**

```
$ php -v
PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.2 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Jun 13 2012 17:20:55) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.1.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2010, by Derick Rethans
    with Suhosin v0.9.33, Copyright (c) 2007-2012, by SektionEins GmbH

$ uname -a
Linux desktop 3.2.0-26-generic-pae #41-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 14 16:45:14 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: This looks *really* strange, especially when sorting the array and such. What are you trying to do?

Comment: This is random by probability generator test... I need to get closer % values in result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sum    = max($chances);
```

`max()` dosn't sum, use `array_sum()` insted

I got this result:

```
Case    Count   Orig    Result
case1   11068   10%     11%
case2   29672   30%     30%
case3   59260   60%     59%
```

From running this version of your code:

```
<?php

function probability($chances)
{
    asort($chances);
    $sum    = array_sum($chances);
    $random = mt_rand(1, $sum);

    foreach($chances as $key => $chance)
    {
        $random -= $chance;
        if($random <= 0)
        {
            return $key;
        }
    }

    return $key;
}

$chances['case1'] = 10;
$chances['case2'] = 30;
$chances['case3'] = 60;

$result = array();

for($i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++)
{
    @$result[probability($chances)]++;
}

asort($result);
$sum = array_sum($result);

echo "Case\tCount\tOrig\tResult\n";

foreach($result as $key => $value)
{
    echo "$key\t$value\t".$chances[$key]."%\t".round($value / $sum * 100)."%\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: Oh, sorry - that's left from previous test and it doesn't make any difference in this particular case!

Answer (score 2):

Your random number generation is flawed.

First of all, consider removing the `asort` call. It does not do anything useful and it is confusing (as well as slow). You are sorting the array 100000 times! It is better to add a pre-condition that the array is sorted (and sort it once before your loop) or implement an algorithm where sorting isn't needed.

Second, you need to make sure that the probability of hitting each case is correct for every case. These are your probabilities now:

```
case1: 10 % (1 <= $random <= 10)
case2: 20 % (11 <= $random <= 30)
case3: 70 % (everything that didn't match previous cases)
```

What you really need to do is something like this:

```
function probability($chances) {
    $sum    = array_sum($chances);
    $random = mt_rand(1, $sum);

    $add = 0;
    foreach($chances as $key => $chance) {
        if($random <= $chance + $add)
            return $key;
        else
            $add += $chance;
    }

    return $key;
}
```

This will give you the expected result:

```
case1: 10 % (1 <= $random <= 10)
case2: 30 % (11 <= $random <= 40)
case3: 60 % (41 <= $random <= 100)
```

Comment: asort() is to start from lesser value

Comment: Roman, it was already sorted! It's better to sort once and not every single time. Also, with my solution the array does not need to be sorted at all.

Comment: In your solution, yes. But if array would not be sorted on top of my code, the method would fail completely if passed data is not ordered.

Comment: Your solution failed even with the sorting ;-) But seriously, in your solution the array was sorted 100000 times! It may be better to require a sorted array as a pre-condition to the function.

Comment: Yes, it did - that's why I posted the question ;-) In real environment it doesn't matter where you sort it because it will be executed once anyway.

Comment: Maybe it even like this: function probability($chances) {

    $sum    = array_sum($chances);
    $random = mt_rand(1, $sum);

    $add = 0;

    foreach($chances as $key => $chance)
        if($random <= $add += $chance)
            return $key;
        
}

Answer (score 1):

> First off, the comparison inside `probability` is wrong, it should be `<=` and not `<`.

This should at least make the results more consistent (i.e. 10, 20, 70)

> Secondly, `case3` is double counted (if nr <= 60 and if nr > 60).

I would propose making this change to the code:

```
function probability($chances)
{
    $sum    = array_sum($chances);
    $random = mt_rand(1, $sum);

    foreach($chances as $key => $chance) {
        if ($random <= $chance) {
            return $key;
        }
    }

    return 'rest';
}
```

Then add 'rest' in the `$chances` array. This must appear in sorted order.

```
$chances['case1'] = 10;
$chances['case2'] = 30;
$chances['case3'] = 60;
$chances['rest'] = 'NA'; // for 60 < x <= 100
```

Outcome:

```
Case    Count   Orig    Result
case1   10083   10%     10%
case2   19965   30%     20%
case3   30084   60%     30%
rest    39868   NA%     40%
```

Comment: Yes, I see the reason now. Thanks!